# How to list all /dev/disks, not partitions ending in s1, s2, ...?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to list (output) the drive its Mac OS X name from the serial number in the Bash 3.2 shell on the command line. For this I need to loop through all block devices not being a partition. So I need a better replacement for this bash loop: `for disk in /dev/disk*; do …; done`

I do want to use `ls` **only**, eventually with a wildcard pattern, without piping (through `grep`) and without other utils (like `find`).

It is like `ls /dev/disk*` but not matching the partitions ending in `s1` (like `/dev/disk0s1`), `s2` etcetera.

#### Regression

The failing attempts:

```
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s][!1-9]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s,!1-9]
$ ls /dev/disk* -d -- *[!s][1-9]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s,1-9]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s][0-9]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s]*
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!\s1-9]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s1-9]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*([!s1-9])
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]*[!s]*[0-9]
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9][0-9]
$ ls /dev/disk* --ignore="disk*s?"
$ ls /dev/disk* -I "*s?"
$ ls /dev/disk* -I "*s[1-9]"
$ ls /dev/disk*[!s?]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ksh`'s extended glob:

```
ls /dev/+(disk?|disk??)
```

for `bash` you have to turn on extended glob

```
shopt -s extglob
ls /dev/+(disk?|disk??)
```

Comment: Please no externals, not even turning on extended globbing. `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

Comment: @Pro Backup- Yah, you get that error if you don't have extended glob set. Please explain why you wish to limit your shell's features.

Comment: I don't dare to change shell options, potentially breaking the execution of other bash/shell scripts.

Comment: @Pro Backup- Well, setting `extended glob` will not "break" your bash scripts, just as setting `null glob` in your answer does not "break" anything. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls /dev/disk[0-9]{,[0-9]}
/dev/disk0  /dev/disk11 /dev/disk2  /dev/disk4  /dev/disk6  /dev/disk8
/dev/disk10 /dev/disk12 /dev/disk3  /dev/disk5  /dev/disk7  /dev/disk9
```